# Missing api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1.0 dll

Tags: windows, dll, visual-c++

I'm having problem running [cmder](http://cmder.net)
and I got this error message

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

I'm in Windows 7 x86
I've installed VC++ redist 2013 and 2015 but no luck

Comment: It doesn't listed on the website, but I read the instruction here https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to install the **[Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226)** This update install the missing `Api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Visual Studio C++ 2015 Update 3 .  If it is currently installed, it should give you the option to run a repair.  Run that repair.

or try to download this update  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows
This is Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows which can help you for sure find your OS then download and instlal
or you can try this solutions
This is for the [Skype can’t start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing](http://fanyit.com/problems-solutions-it/skype-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing/)  but have good explanation for how to download and install this Universal upate for C Runtime   and this is happend on more program becuase is missing this file but for all you can resolve with this update

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got an error message every time I tried to install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) or [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). So I decided to tear the installer apart and manually copy the required dll files to `C:\Windows\system32`. I haven't seen any side effects so far, but you should write down which dll files you copy, so that you can undo it any time.

1. [Download](https://github.com/Bioruebe/UniExtract2/releases) and extract the Universal Extractor zip
2. Run UniExtract.exe
3. Select the installer (in my case `vc_redist_x86`)
4. Click OK (it will create a Folder called `vc_redist_x86`)
5. Open `UniExtract.exe` again
6. This time select `vc_redist_x86\AttachedContainer\packages\vcRuntimeMinimun_x86\.msi` (For 64 bit Windows it will be a slightly different path)
7. Click OK (It will create a filder called `vcRuntimeMinimun_x86`.
8. Go to `vc_runtimeMinimum_x86\vc_runtimeMinimum_x86\System` (For 64 bit Windows the path will be slightly different) and you'll see all the DLLs including `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`.
9. Copy all those DLLs to `C:\Windows\system32` and skip for every DLL that already exists.