# How to install the DLL files in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, python

I just installed python in my computer and set the path successfully. And Now, When i am trying to run a python program from the command prompt it showing the error '**api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll**'. Then i downloaded the missing files from the Internet but when i am trying to copying the downloaded files into Sys32 folder it showing the error of '**Access Denied'**. So, question is how to install the missing dll i.e how to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I install the missing `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`?

This DLL is part of the [Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows):

> The Windows 10 Universal CRT is a Windows operating system component that enables CRT functionality on the Windows operating system. This update allows Windows desktop applications that depend on the Windows 10 Universal CRT release to run on earlier Windows operating systems.

The above link includes full installations instructions, which depend on exactly which version of Windows you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, to install a DLL you can place the DLL pretty much anywhere and then use the `regsvr32.exe` command. You're getting an error because you need administrator rights to modify the `Sys32` folder.

However in your case, the error message is caused because the KB2999226 (Universal CRT), which is part of the Visual C++ Redistributable, failed to install. The Universal CRT fails to install if the necessary prerequisites (other updates) have not been installed yet.

To solve your problem, you need to go into Windows Update, install all updates, reboot, uninstall the Visual Studio redistributable and then reinstall it again.

Full instructions can be found at https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0dll-is-missing-f2702.html