# The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: windows-7

When starting certain programs on Windows 7 I'm getting the following error message:

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer

[image]

Clicking "OK" dismisses the dialog and allows the software to run without any problems, but the error repeats next time I run the software.

Unfortunately reinstalling the software does not fix the problem.

This is getting very annoying. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### What causes this error and how do I fix it?

It happens when applications built using the Windows 10 SDK are executed on earlier version of Windows.

This creates a dependency on [Windows 10 Universal CRT (C Runtime)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/).

To fix it, install the [Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows):

> The Windows 10 Universal CRT is a Windows operating system component
>   that enables CRT functionality on the Windows operating system. This
>   update allows Windows desktop applications that depend on the Windows
>   10 Universal CRT release to run on earlier Windows operating systems.
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 creates a dependency on the Universal CRT
>   when applications are built by using the Windows 10 Software
>   Development Kit (SDK). You can install this update on earlier Windows
>   operating systems to enable these applications to run correctly.

---

#### Further reading

- [Introducing the Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/)
- [The Great C Runtime (CRT) Refactoring](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/06/10/the-great-c-runtime-crt-refactoring/)

Comment: If a simple Hello World is compiled with VS2017, the executable depends on `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` but if compiled with mingw, it depends on `msvcrt.dll`. Why?

Comment: @Biswa No idea. I've never used Visual Studio ... however I would guess that VS uses the Windows 10 SDK and mingw doesn't.

Comment: @Biswa: That's MinGW being stupid. The DLL it depends on is [effectively the Visual C *4.2* runtime (yes, it's over 10 versions old by now) from before the Windows 95 days](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273/). It's not a library anyone should ever depend on.

Comment: But then why `Clicking "OK" dismisses the dialog and allows the software to run without any problems, `

Comment: @edc65 No idea ...

Comment: @edc65 It's possible the library is compiled into the executable but not actually used. It's also possible you're just not using a feature in the software that requires this library.

Comment: @Joey: I think you mean the Visual C++ 4.2 C runtime.  There was a Microsoft C 4.x compiler, but it didn't carry the moniker "Visual" and never had a 32-bit version.  And that MSVCRT.DLL has been updated *many* times in the meantime with bug fixes and updates to e.g. Daylight Savings Time rules, but as you suggest, it is still ABI-compatible with Visual C++ 4.2